# Unable to connect remote mysql

Tags: java, mysql, remote-access

I am trying to access remote mysql database from apache netbeans ide, Using services net beans got this error message every time:
Timeout expired. IDE unable to establish connection. Check your proxy settings or try again later. The server may be unavailable at the moment.   You may also want to make sure that your firewall is not blocking network traffic.
I have done the following things

1. Installed mysql 8.0.27 on remote server ubuntu 20.04
   2  Created a User having access with %
2. changed bind-address = 127.0.0.1 to bind-address 0.0.0.0 in mysqld.cnf file
3. mysql server is running.
4. mysql port 3306

Still I am unable to connect to database from netbeans ide.

furthermore, I also have another server (vm) running windows server 2019 but on this server i can not connect to the database.

Comment: Did your firewall allows port 3306 ?

Comment: And have you checked the firewall? Install and run tcptraceroute with `tcptraceroute <IP address> 3306`. Tell us how it is connected together.

Comment: firewall allow port 3306

Comment: I have traces the router from a website it says "No reply for 5 hops. Assuming we reached firewall."

Comment: I am also unable to ping my both servers using their ip addresses(windows 2019  & Ubuntu 20.04)